# How to uninstall bluej? Is netbeans better?

Tags: java, netbeans, bluej

Can i have intalled on my computer  both bluej and netbeans? I have bluej now, if i uninstall it , everything related with it will be  unistalled to (every libraries). And generally is netbeans better option?

Comment: Please note that your question _"And generally is netbeans better option?"_  is off topic here: ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

As per first question, you can install BlueJ, Netbeans, Intellij, Eclipse any other IDE all can be installed in the computer. I have installed both Intellij and Eclise in my system. It is up to the user about how many IDEs to be installed. Besides, each IDE has its own speciality and beauty. **It is too broad to compare** which one is better. As far as your learning is concerned, you have liberty to use any IDE.

Comment: thanks, and how to check if you have current java version? Is Java 8 the newest right now?

Comment: To know Java version, open command prompt and type java -version

Comment: To see all java version history, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: @Gas4321 The latest long-term support (LTS) version is Java 11. The absolute latest version is Java 13.

Comment: omg it is changing so fast

Comment: @Sambit Typing **java -version** from the command prompt doesn't tell you anything about which version of Java is being used by NetBeans itself, nor any projects within NetBeans. In NetBeans you can specify multiple Java platforms, and implicitly or explicitly select the one to be used for any project. Which version of **java.exe** happens to be found through **PATH** from the command line is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, I agree sir.

Comment: @Gas4321 When Java 9 was released they moved to a six month release cycle. Java 13 was released in September 2019 and Java 14 is set to be released in March 2020. The next long-term support version will be Java 17 which should be released around September 2021.